# Group or sort list/array by number of matching keywords

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, linq

What's a good, efficient way in C# to group or sort the elements of a string array or List by the number of matching keywords between each & every element. Elements with most matching keywords should be placed near each other.

For example, if the collection is:

```cs
string[] movies = {
    "Star Wars Episode IV A New Hope",
    "Force of Hunger",
    "The Hunger Games Mockingjay",
    "Jaws 2",
    "The Shawshank Redemption",
    "Hunger Pain",
    "The Hunger Games",
    "Jaws: The Revenge",
    "The Hunger Games Catching Fire",
    "Rogue One A Star Wars Story",
    "Aqua Teen Hunger Force",
    "The Force Awakens Star Wars",
};
```

Then the result after processing should be somewhat similar to:

```cs
{
    "The Hunger Games Mockingjay",
    "The Hunger Games Catching Fire",
    "The Hunger Games",

    "Aqua Teen Hunger Force",
    "Force of Hunger",

    "Rogue One A Star Wars Story",
    "The Force Awakens Star Wars"
    "Star Wars Episode IV A New Hope",

    "Jaws: The Revenge",
    "Jaws 2",

    "Hunger Pain",

    "The Shawshank Redemption",
};
```

Comment: I could have thought of Alpha numeric sorting but that is not your requirement, you need specific grouping which needs custom coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the approach I would take:

1. Decompose each title into a normalized set of words, excluding "noise" words like "a", "an" and "the".
2. Find the intersections (commonalities) of each pair of word sets.
3. Add each title to a dictionary of sets of intersections keyed by title. Add each intersection to the set for that title.
4. Finally, sort the dictionary by intersection size (largest first), then by the words in the intersection, and finally by the title, to arrive at the final list of titles.

Here's what it might look like in code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] movies = {
            "Star Wars Episode IV A New Hope",
            "Force of Hunger",
            "The Hunger Games Mockingjay",
            "Jaws 2",
            "The Shawshank Redemption",
            "Hunger Pain",
            "The Hunger Games",
            "Jaws: The Revenge",
            "The Hunger Games Catching Fire",
            "Rogue One A Star Wars Story",
            "Aqua Teen Hunger Force",
            "The Force Awakens Star Wars",
        };

        List<HashSet<string>> titleWords = movies
            .Select(m => new HashSet<string>(
                m.Split(new char[] { ' ', ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(w => w.ToLower())
                .Where(w => w != "a" && w != "an" && w != "the")))
            .ToList();

        var titles = new Dictionary<string, SortedSet<Commonality>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < titleWords.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < titleWords.Count; j++)
            {
                var wordsInCommon = titleWords[i]
                    .Intersect(titleWords[j])
                    .OrderBy(w => w)
                    .ToList();
                Commonality c = new Commonality(wordsInCommon);
                AddCommonalities(titles, movies[i], c);
                AddCommonalities(titles, movies[j], c);
            }
        }

        string[] groupedTitles = titles
            .OrderBy(k => k.Value.First())
            .ThenBy(k => k.Key)
            .Select(k => k.Key)
            .ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", groupedTitles));
    }

    private static void AddCommonalities(Dictionary<string, SortedSet<Commonality>> dict, string title, Commonality c)
    {
        SortedSet<Commonality> commonalities;
        if (!dict.TryGetValue(title, out commonalities))
        {
            commonalities = new SortedSet<Commonality>();
            dict.Add(title, commonalities);
        }
        commonalities.Add(c);
    }
}

class Commonality : IComparable<Commonality>
{
    public string JoinedWords { get; private set; }
    public int WordCount { get; private set; }

    public Commonality(List<string> words)
    {
        JoinedWords = string.Join(" ", words);
        WordCount = words.Count;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Commonality that = obj as Commonality;
        return (that != null && that.JoinedWords == JoinedWords);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return JoinedWords.GetHashCode();
    }

    public int CompareTo(Commonality other)
    {
        int r = other.WordCount - WordCount;
        if (r == 0) return string.CompareOrdinal(JoinedWords, other.JoinedWords);
        return r;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return WordCount + " " + JoinedWords;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Aqua Teen Hunger Force
Force of Hunger
The Hunger Games
The Hunger Games Catching Fire
The Hunger Games Mockingjay
Rogue One A Star Wars Story
Star Wars Episode IV A New Hope
The Force Awakens Star Wars
Hunger Pain
Jaws 2
Jaws: The Revenge
The Shawshank Redemption
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ksMMY6

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I got as far as intersection (and played with Jaccard Similarity as well) on my own in the meantime, but your implementation of `commonalities` is pretty cool. Anyway to optimize it and speed it up (PLINQ or `Parallel.For` for those two `for` loops), specially if the source dataset is larger?

Answer (score 1):

```
        string[] movies = {
                "Star Wars Episode IV A New Hope",
                "Force of Hunger",
                "The Hunger Games Mockingjay",
                "Jaws 2",
                "The Shawshank Redemption",
                "Hunger Pain",
                "The Hunger Games",
                "Jaws: The Revenge",
                "The Hunger Games Catching Fire",
                "Rogue One A Star Wars Story",
                "Aqua Teen Hunger Force",
                "The Force Awakens Star Wars",
            };

        string[] kw = { "Star", "Wars", "Force", "Hunger", "Games", "The", "Jaws" };


        var group  = movies.GroupBy(p => kw.Count(k => p.Contains(k))).OrderByDescending(p=> p.Key);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var g in group)
        {
          sb.AppendLine("Group : " + g.Key);
            foreach (var s in g)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(s);
            }
        }
```

And the result will be

```
   Group : 4
   The Force Awakens Star Wars
   Group : 3
   The Hunger Games Mockingjay
   The Hunger Games
   The Hunger Games Catching Fire
   Group : 2
   Star Wars Episode IV A New Hope
   Force of Hunger
   Jaws: The Revenge
   Rogue One A Star Wars Story
   Aqua Teen Hunger Force
   Group : 1
   Jaws 2
   The Shawshank Redemption
   Hunger Pain
```

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. Seems like you've used predefined keywords, which isn't suitable. Maybe I wasn't clear, but keywords simply refers to the bag of words in each element of the array.

Comment: I would rate this as a good answer, even if not complete, since there's no defined pattern in the question to run a standard data grouping operation, please define that first or it needs custom logic +1